# laravel-soap - can't get the response outside of the wrapper

Tags: php, soap, laravel, singleton

All,

I'm trying to get https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap to work, but no love. This is likely not a problem with the package, but a gap in my understanding of PHP (which I haven't used in a number of years).

The doco says:

```
SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
    $service->name('currency')->wsdl('http://currencyconverter.kowabunga.net/converter.asmx?WSDL');
});

$data = [
    'CurrencyFrom' => 'USD',
    'CurrencyTo'   => 'EUR',
    'RateDate'     => '2014-06-05',
    'Amount'       => '1000'
];

SoapWrapper::service('currency',function($service) use ($data) {
    var_dump($service->getFunctions());
    var_dump($service->call('GetConversionAmount',$data)->GetConversionAmountResult);
});
```

Now that all works great... But how on earth do I get the response from $service->call... back out into my application?

I've tried

```
$response = SoapWrapper::service('currency',function($service) use ($data) {
    $service->call('GetConversionAmount',$data)->GetConversionAmountResult;
});
```

but that just returns the soap client response.

I've tried:

```
$response = '';

SoapWrapper::service('currency',function($service) use ($data) {
    $response = $service->call('GetConversionAmount',$data)->GetConversionAmountResult;
});
```

but that does nothing as it seems anything inside that wrapper call only exists inside that block.

They are really the only two things I could think of doing as I'm not very familiar with all these singleton calls that seem to occur in Laravel (I was also of the opinion that they should be avoided like the plague).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the creator of the laravel-soap package.
You can give the data back like so:

```
$response = '';
$data = [
    'CurrencyFrom' => 'USD',
    'CurrencyTo'   => 'EUR',
    'RateDate'     => '2014-06-05',
    'Amount'       => '1000'
];

SoapWrapper::service('currency',function($service) use ($data,&$response) {
    $response = $service->call('GetConversionAmount',$data)->GetConversionAmountResult;
});

var_dump($response);
```

This is called passing by reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php
I've you got some issues with the laravel-soap package please create a issue on Github.

Comment: The response is returned as an object so you can simply do $response->multiMessageNewListResponse->hasMoreMessages